# How to do conditional select in jqxGrid?

Tags: jqxgrid

I have a requirement where I select a `jqxGrid` Cell, but I do some processing and delete some rows in the same grid.

For eg. If I select row with index = 4, and after doing some processing in the rowselect event, I delete rows with index 1 and 2 and update the grid with new data. Now my row which I selected last time will come at index 2. But my grid shows the row with index = 4 ( selected last time ) as selected / highlighted.

Is there any way to prevent this or can we have some before select function that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use an `id` instead of directly select based on the bound index or display index. You can set an `id` field in the data adapter as long as you have a unique identifier column in your data set. Then you can select rows based on this `id` by calling first the jqx-grid API mehtod `getrowboundindexbyid`.